# How to use apt-get to install packages without one specify package?

Tags: apt

For example:

The following command will install all packages that match it's pattern:

```
  sudo apt-get install k3b-*
```

If I want to use that instruction but don't want to install one specific package with broken dependencies, how do I do that?

I have tried this but not works.

sudo apt-get install      "$(apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames k3b | grep -v extrathemes | tr '\n' ' ')" :

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/ai/cram/roslisp_repl$ sudo apt-get install      "$(apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames k3b | grep -v extrathemes | tr '\n' ' ')"
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package k3b-dbg k3b-data k3b 

 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/ai/cram/roslisp_repl$
```

Thank you~

Comment: Sam - I'm confused - you've marked the question as solved but have edited the question saying otherwise... is the question solved or not - please update as appropriate.

Comment: Yes,enzotib's answer is solved my question with 2 steps. But con-f-use's answer is trying to solve my question with another way(1 step) but with errors. I want to learn more so I revise my origin post to let @con-f-use know what I am tring.

Comment: You should remove double quotes around `$(instructions)`.

Comment: Won't `sudo apt-get install k3b-*` fail if there is a file that matches the pattern in the current directory?

Comment: I haven't happened this situation,and I solve it in second way by removing "" quote.

Comment: @svick: of course, in such a case you should quote at least the `*` char

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
list=$(apt-cache --names-only search ^k3b-* | awk '{ print $1 }' | \
    grep -v bad-pkg)
sudo apt-get install $list
```

Answer (score 4):

Say you don't want to install the k3b-extrathemes package. There might be no practical way to do this but to list all the packages except for the one: `sudo apt-get install k3b-data k3b-dbg`.

However you can do that with some aid:

```
sudo apt-get install $(apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames k3b \
    | grep -v extrathemes | tr '\n' ' ')
```

That's not terribly partical. `apt-cache ...` returns the name of the  packages, `grep -v PACKAGENAME` excludes the packages and the `tr` command replaces new lines by spaces.

Comment: I have revised my origin post for this instruction's result.Why can't locate packages?

Comment: You should remove double quotes around `$(instructions)`.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a much simpler way of doing this:

```
sudo aptitude install <package>
```

This will use [`aptitude`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aptitude) instead of [`apt-get`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt) - which provides you with more options. When you see something like the following:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ...
0 packages upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 130 MB/130 MB of archives. After unpacking 216 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

Instead of pressing 'y', type the following:

```
-<package_to_skip>
```

That's a '-' followed by the name of the package to skip. Then you can proceed with the installation as per normal.

Comment: Newer releases don't install `aptitude` by default, but you can easily install it using `sudo apt-get install aptitude` or from the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially do this with apt; if you want to install `foo` but not `bar`, do this:

```
sudo apt install foo bar-
```

i.e. append a hyphen to `bar`. From the apt-get man page:

> If a hyphen is appended to the package name (with no
>   intervening space), the identified package will be removed if it is
>   installed. Similarly a plus sign can be used to designate a package
>   to install.

This apparently works for packages that would be installed, as well as those that are already installed.

Comment: Intriguing, but failed with apt install mopidy* mopidy-podcast-gpodcast- mopidy-podcast-itunes mopidy-podcast-   .
Ended up using mopidy-[^p].*